Typegoose discriminators and indexes
I am using nodejs with typegoose, and I have an issue with indexes and discriminators that started when I upgraded mongodb client package from v4.7.x to v6.8.0
I have a model like:
@index({ make: 1, color: 1 }, { unique: true, background: false })
@modelOptions({
    options: { allowMixed: Severity.ALLOW },
    schemaOptions: { collection: 'cars', discriminatorKey: 'make' },
})
class Car extends defaultClasses.TimeStamps {
    @prop({ required: true })
    make: string;

    @prop({ required: true })
    color: string;
}

const CarModel = getModelForClass(Car);

class Mazda extends Car {}
const MazdaModel = getDiscriminatorModelForClass(CarModel, Mazda, 'mazda');

class Cadillac extends Car {}
const CadillacModel = getDiscriminatorModelForClass(CarModel, Cadillac, 'cadi');

This worked fine with v4.7.x but now with the new version, when I call listIndex() I get something like:
[{"v":2,"unique":true,"key":{"make":1,"color":1},"name":"make_1_color_1","background":false,"partialFilterExpression":{"make":"mazda"}}]

or
[{"v":2,"unique":true,"key":{"make":1,"color":1},"name":"make_1_color_1","background":false,"partialFilterExpression":{"make":"cadi"}}]

But in any case uniqueness is forced only on one of the "make" options because of partialFilterExpression option.
When using 4.7.x with the same code partialFilterExpression was not added and index created ok.

This is likely a side-effect of typegoose "cloning" index definitions from the super class(es) and mongoose trying to make the index for that discriminator only.
This can be disabled on the discriminators by setting @modelOptions option disableLowerIndexes.
To get the actual index created, you will likely have to run syncIndexes (or just createIndexes).
Example:
// NodeJS: 22.8.0
// MongoDB: 7.0 (Docker)
// Typescript 5.3.3
import { defaultClasses, getDiscriminatorModelForClass, getModelForClass, index, modelOptions, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose'; // @typegoose/typegoose@12.9.0
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'; // mongoose@8.8.0

@index({ make: 1, color: 1 }, { unique: true, background: false })
@modelOptions({
  schemaOptions: { collection: 'cars', discriminatorKey: 'make' },
})
class Car extends defaultClasses.TimeStamps {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public make!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public color!: string;
}

const CarModel = getModelForClass(Car);

@modelOptions({ options: { disableLowerIndexes: true } })
class Mazda extends Car {}

const MazdaModel = getDiscriminatorModelForClass(CarModel, Mazda, 'mazda');

@modelOptions({ options: { disableLowerIndexes: true } })
class Cadillac extends Car {}

const CadillacModel = getDiscriminatorModelForClass(CarModel, Cadillac, 'cadi');

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/`, {
    dbName: 'verifyMASTER',
  });

  await CarModel.syncIndexes();

  // the following 2 dont create any indexes as they dont have any defined
  await MazdaModel.syncIndexes();
  await CadillacModel.syncIndexes();

  await MazdaModel.create({ color: 'blue' });
  await CadillacModel.create({ color: 'red' });

  await mongoose.disconnect();
}

main();

(Testing Repository & Branch)
PS: For questions regarding typegoose / mongoose, it would be better to provide the mongoose & typegoose versions instead of the underlying mongodb driver version.
PPS: I dont recommend blankly setting allowMixed: Severity.ALLOW, only set it if actually necessary and also consider only setting it for specific properties.
